# Convert SQL query result to Base64string in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, base64

I have a stored procedure that executes a `select` statement with a a big XML as its result.

Is there any way to convert the whole XML to a base-64 string in the same stored procedure? The shown result should become a base-64 string.

The select statement looks like this:

```
Select * 
From Anvandare 
For Xml Raw, Root('<rootName>')
```

What I am looking for to do is something like this:

```
CAST(Select * from Anvandare For Xml Raw, Root('<rootName>') as Base64)
```

FYI: I know this is wrong but I hope you understand the idea.

The XML that is returning is rather big it has 1000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For XML to Base64, this might work.**

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT * FROM Anvandare FOR Xml Raw, Root('rootName')) as varbinary(max)) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64
```

**Convert back from Base64 to XML**

```
SELECT CAST( CAST( 'c3RyaW5n' as XML ).value('.','varbinary(max)') AS varchar(max) )
```

Hope that helps !!!

Comment: one more quick question, is it possible to make the encoded result smaller? its pretty big almost as big as the xml itself?

Comment: May be not. And you don't need to worry as NVARCHAR(Max) can store up to 2GB of characters.